# $m$ by $n$ matrix or $m$ cross $n$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

What should we call for an $m \times n$ matrix $A$?

$m$ by $n$ matrix or $m$ cross $n$ matrix.

What should we call for a cartesian product $C \times D$ of two sets?

$C$ by $D$ or $C \times D$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

m ***by*** n or m ***cross*** n.

It depends upon your locality slang and has nothing to do with maths.

Moreover, ***by*** may not be a common preference for teaching professionals, since their students might confuse it with the division(/).

Eg.:  2/3 sounds like 2 by 3

Hope this helps :)